# R: Error on importing Json

Tags: r, json, data-import

I want to import my `JSON` file into R. Installed the packages.
This is what I tried ->

```
library(rjson)
JsonData <- fromJson(file= "<filename.json>")
```

Also tried the file path and `jsonlite` package. I get this error --->

> Error in file(con,"r"): can not open the connection.
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       cannot open file '': invalid argument

I have set up every thing right, but its just wont work. I also tried other available options too!

Comment: `<filename.json>` is not a valid name for a file

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan I tried every thing in from the other question!

Comment: @Onyambu was just for illustration

Answer (score 0):

`JsonData <- fromJson(file= "<filename.json>")`

should be

`JsonData <- fromJSON(file= "filename.json")`

Two things: you should change `fromJson` to `fromJSON` (remember, R is case-sensitive), and you should remove the greater-than and less-than symbols (< and >) in your file path

Comment: thank you for the answer. I still get an error --> Error in fromJSON(file= "BMVI_daten_BBA_Alle_Tech.json") unexpected chatacter '<ef>'

Comment: @NatalieSablowski interesting. Can you paste your JSON [here](https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator) (it will validate whether or not it contains errors in JSON syntax)

Comment: it wont load. There is an error. I converted this json from an csv online ( but here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com it says that the json is just right - @user5783745